# TeamCity: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm encountering an issue when running tests in my CI environment. The configuration works fine on MacOS 10.11.6 (El Capitan), with Node v6.0.0 / npm 3.8.6, but on a TeamCity 9.1.6 agent running Windows with Node v4.2.2 / npm 2.14.7, it fails miserably with an error of `PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms`.

Here's an example stacktrace on TeamCity:

```
[08:58:40][exec] 02 11 2016 08:58:41.095:DEBUG [config]: autoWatch set to false, because of singleRun
[08:58:40][exec] 02 11 2016 08:58:41.102:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin karma-jasmine.
[08:58:40][exec] 02 11 2016 08:58:41.107:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin karma-chrome-launcher.
[08:58:40][exec] 02 11 2016 08:58:41.121:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin karma-firefox-launcher.
[08:58:40][exec] 02 11 2016 08:58:41.128:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin karma-phantomjs-launcher.
[08:58:40][exec] 02 11 2016 08:58:41.263:DEBUG [web-server]: Instantiating middleware
[08:58:41][exec] 02 11 2016 08:58:41.595:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9877/
[08:58:41][exec] 02 11 2016 08:58:41.596:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
[08:58:41][exec] 02 11 2016 08:58:41.616:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
[08:58:41][exec] 02 11 2016 08:58:41.618:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at E:\TCA\3\temp\buildTmp\karma-47802965
[08:58:41][exec] 02 11 2016 08:58:41.631:DEBUG [launcher]: E:\TCA\3\work\f900f2fe23d6c9b0\Preview\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs E:\TCA\3\temp\buildTmp\karma-47802965/capture.js
[08:59:41][exec] 02 11 2016 08:59:41.621:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[08:59:43][exec] 02 11 2016 08:59:43.624:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
[08:59:45][exec] 02 11 2016 08:59:45.627:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS was not killed by SIGKILL in 2000 ms, continuing.
[08:59:45][exec] 02 11 2016 08:59:45.628:DEBUG [launcher]: Process PhantomJS exited with code -1
[08:59:45][exec] 02 11 2016 08:59:45.629:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir E:\TCA\3\temp\buildTmp\karma-47802965
[08:59:45][exec] 02 11 2016 08:59:45.637:DEBUG [launcher]: PhantomJS failed (timeout). Not restarting.
[08:59:45][exec] 02 11 2016 08:59:45.638:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
[08:59:45][exec] 02 11 2016 08:59:45.639:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
[08:59:45][exec] Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed.  Use --force to continue.
[08:59:45][exec] 
[08:59:45][exec] Aborted due to warnings.
[08:59:45][exec] npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Here's a snippet of package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bower": "latest",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-istanbul-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "grunt-karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "matchdep": "^1.0.1"
},
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/.bin/grunt default"
}
```

And here's a snippet of karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
'use strict';

config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-firefox-launcher',
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
    ],
    files: [
        <...>
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress']
    port: 9877,
    runnerPort: 9101,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: true
});
```

Comment: [Related issue on Karma PhantomJS Github](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/84).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue solved! In our CI environment, we aren't getting the node modules by running `npm install` - we are zipping the node_modules directory locally and adding it to our source code.

Zipping it on a Mac and exploding it on Windows and attempting to use those modules, especially `phantomjs-prebuilt`, is the reason why it wasn't capturing.

I zipped it from Windows instead and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the *`PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing`* problem locally and after some experimenting it turned out that it may have been caused by:

1. Clash between PhantomJS available from classpath vs
   `phatomjs-prebuilt` downloaded to project's node_modules. I just removed the globally available one.
2. Missing `PHANTOMJS_CDNURL` environment (system) variable, pointing to a maven repository, check [where to get PhantomJS](https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs#deciding-where-to-get-phantomjs).

Comment: Thank you for your response, @jediz. However, there is no other instance of PhantomJS except for the prebuilt one in node_modules. Additionally, it doesn't seem like there's an issue downloading PhantomJS, as we unfortunately have node_modules as a zipped directory that is unzipped during builds.